# How to deserialize Json in a Json?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Here is my json returned by php web application:

```
{"subtotal":475,"tax":47.5,"discount_section":[{"amount":237.5,"name":"test prior for percentage discount
"}],"grand_total_incl_tax":332.5}
```

I use c# and json.net to decode the abvoe json

```
var cart = webClient.DownloadString("http://localhost/m1/pos_addToCart.php?pidstr=" + pid_str);

dynamic result = JObject.Parse(cart);
```

But there is an error on this line:

```
order_discount_section.Text = result.discount_section;
```

Error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' to 'string'
```

How to convert this json to String like:

```
Key1 = Value1
Key2 = Value2
Key3 = Value3
```

Comment: discount_section is an array. try result.discount_section[0].name

Comment: Try casting result to a dynamic. That should do it i think based on the above examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon your supplied json `discount_section` is a map so it can't be expressed as a `string`.  It's like trying to convert a dictionary to a `string` or an `array` to a `string`.

If you want it as a `string` representation then adding `ToString()` after the `result.discount_section` (i.e. `result.discount_section.ToString()`) should accomplish that.

Though I would suggest that you either store the data through placeholder values such as:

`string name = result.discount_section[0].name` (same with amount but float/decimal/double...).

Or if you wanted it as text have it as

```
text = "Name: " + result.discount_section[0].name 
       + "Amount: " + result.discount_section[0].amount.ToString();`
```

Obviously using a stringbuilder or other tool would be better (such as `string.format`) but I'll leave that as an 'exercise' to you.

**Edit:**
The for loop for all of the results.

```
totalText = ""
for (i = 0; i < result.discount_section.length; i++) {
    totalText += "Name: " + result.discount_section[i].name + "Amount: " + result.discount_section[i].amount.ToString() + "\n";
}
```

Obviously if you wanted an array of strings then you would just build an array then just use i as your string array index as well.

Comment: I am upvoting your answer due to it`s content. But I recommend you to format your answer, cause really hard to read.

Comment: Sure :) I just had a phone and couldn't do it properly will format it a little more nicely and thanks Thili77 for the edits too.

Comment: if the result.discount_section has more than two array? how do i loop through that?

Comment: Then just put an for loop.  I'll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Json.NET` provides a correct behaviour.

As from your example string, it can be seen, that `discount_section` is a json array, or `JArray`, descendant of `JToken` after parsing to `JObject`.

If you want to access inner member of this array, as `name` for example, you should call it as

```
order_discount_section.Text = result.discount_section[0].name;
```

If you want to write the full notation of `discount_section` as is, you should explicitly call `ToString` method:

```
order_discount_section.Text = result.discount_section.ToString();
```

Although, dealing with `dynamic`s is not useful, while your working with separate service responsing in `JSON`. It will be better to define a single class, which will handle json values, so you could not only look what json is passing, but to work with it

Answer (score 0):

You may consider working with objects and deserialize using [JsonConvert.DeserializeObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1_2.htm). Example:

```
class Discount
{
    public Decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

class Response
{
   public Decimal Subtotal { get; set; }
   public Decimal Tax { get; set; }
   public List<Discount> Discount_section { get; set; }
   public Grand_total_incl_tax { get; set; } 
}

var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(cart);
```

This approach is good when object structure is relatively fixed and has the following advantages:

- clear structure
- relevant errors when you have a type mismatch (JSON -> property)

Answer (score 0):

`result.discount_section` is collection. you can not set directly to string variable.

try this.

```
        var result= JObject.Parse(cart);
        dynamic[] discountSection = result["discount_section"].ToArray<dynamic>();
        decimal amount = discountSection[0].amount;
        decimal name = discountSection[0].name;
```

**for dictionary**

```
Dictionary<string,decimal> discountDictionary =  discountSection.ToDictionary<dynamic, string, decimal>((d) => d.name, (d) => d.amount);
```